# Android ImageView - 16:9

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, aspect-ratio

I need to set the Bitmap into ImageView to keep ratio 16:9. Do you have any advice? The main solution is probably in the override method onMeasure of custom ImageView but how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT 01/03/2019:** After all this time, I strongly recommend using `ConstraintLayout` that @Eugene Brusov introduced below. I personally would never use my image view that does Math by overriding onMeasure.

**EDIT 03/29/2018:** My answer below may be simple, but may be too much of raw answer. If you want to utilize what's already given by Google's `ConstraintLayout`, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45822286/3690442) or scroll down and see @Eugene Brusov's answer.

**Old answer:**

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    // some other necessary things

    @Override 
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = getMeasuredWidth();

        //force a 16:9 aspect ratio             
        int height = Math.round(width * .5625f);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

Then in your xml

```
<path.to.package.CustomImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/img"/>
```

Answer (score 39):

Since `PercentFrameLayout` and `PercentRelativeLayout` were deprecated in API level 26.0.0, I'd suggest you to consider using of `ConstraintLayout` to keep ratio 16:9 for your `ImageView`. `ConstraintLayout` is really powerful tool to build Responsive UI for Android platform, you can find more details here [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html).

Here is the example how to build your ImageView into ConstraintLayout to keep 16:9 ratio:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Don't forget to add `constraint-layout` dependency to your module's `build.gradle` file

```
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2"
```

---

Or instead of editing your XML file, edit your layout directly in Layout Editor:

[image: Layout Editor]

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT: Google has officially deprecated the Percent support library starting API 26 and you should move away from it as soon as possible.**

> Set size as a ratio
>   You can set the view size to a ratio such as 16:9 if at least one of the view dimensions is set to "match constraints" (0dp). To enable the ratio, click Toggle Aspect Ratio Constraint (callout 1 in figure 10), and then enter the width:height ratio in the input that appears.
>
> If both the width and height are set to match constraints, you can click Toggle Aspect Ratio Constraint to select which dimension is based on a ratio of the other. The view inspector indicates which is set as a ratio by connecting the corresponding edges with a solid line.
>
> For example, if you set both sides to "match constraints", click Toggle Aspect Ratio Constraint twice to set the width be a ratio of the height. Now the entire size is dictated by the height of the view (which can be defined in any way) as shown in figure below:
>
> [image: The view is set to a 16:9 aspect with the width based on a ratio of the height.]

**More information here: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#adjust-the-view-size**

---

There is something called `PercentFrameLayout` and `PercentRelativeLayout` in the Support library.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <ImageView
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
    app:layout_aspectRatio="178%"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/header_background"/>
  <!-- The rest of your layout -->
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

If you take a closer look at the above layout, you'll see that the `ImageView` in question (that needs to be fixed at 16:9) is wrapped around a `PercentFrameLayout` and there's two attributes set on the `ImageView` that you might not have seen before:

```
app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
app:layout_aspectRatio="178%"
```

So (1) you need to define one of the dimensions (either width or height) to be the *leading* dimension for our `ImageView` in question. In this case the `ImageView` will expand vertically, to it's maximum width (like `android:layout_width="match_parent"`)
And (2) you need to set the aspect ratio in percentage (hence the name of the library) which is in this case 178% (16/9 = 1.77777777778 or more simply put 1.78:1 or 178%).

Read more about the Percent Support Library [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#percent).

Answer (score 5):

Above answers didn't work for me, I found this and worked:

```
public class AspectRatioImageView extends ImageView {
  // NOTE: These must be kept in sync with the AspectRatioImageView attributes in attrs.xml.
  public static final int MEASUREMENT_WIDTH = 0;
  public static final int MEASUREMENT_HEIGHT = 1;

  private static final float DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO = 1f;
  private static final boolean DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO_ENABLED = false;
  private static final int DEFAULT_DOMINANT_MEASUREMENT = MEASUREMENT_WIDTH;

  private float aspectRatio;
  private boolean aspectRatioEnabled;
  private int dominantMeasurement;

  public AspectRatioImageView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
  }

  public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.AspectRatioImageView);
    aspectRatio = a.getFloat(R.styleable.AspectRatioImageView_aspectRatio, DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO);
    aspectRatioEnabled = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.AspectRatioImageView_aspectRatioEnabled,
        DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO_ENABLED);
    dominantMeasurement = a.getInt(R.styleable.AspectRatioImageView_dominantMeasurement,
        DEFAULT_DOMINANT_MEASUREMENT);
    a.recycle();
  }

  @Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (!aspectRatioEnabled) return;

    int newWidth;
    int newHeight;
    switch (dominantMeasurement) {
      case MEASUREMENT_WIDTH:
        newWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        newHeight = (int) (newWidth / aspectRatio);
        break;

      case MEASUREMENT_HEIGHT:
        newHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        newWidth = (int) (newHeight * aspectRatio);
        break;

      default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown measurement with ID " + dominantMeasurement);
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(newWidth, newHeight);
  }

  /** Get the aspect ratio for this image view. */
  public float getAspectRatio() {
    return aspectRatio;
  }

  /** Set the aspect ratio for this image view. This will update the view instantly. */
  public void setAspectRatio(float aspectRatio) {
    this.aspectRatio = aspectRatio;
    if (aspectRatioEnabled) {
      requestLayout();
    }
  }

  /** Get whether or not forcing the aspect ratio is enabled. */
  public boolean getAspectRatioEnabled() {
    return aspectRatioEnabled;
  }

  /** set whether or not forcing the aspect ratio is enabled. This will re-layout the view. */
  public void setAspectRatioEnabled(boolean aspectRatioEnabled) {
    this.aspectRatioEnabled = aspectRatioEnabled;
    requestLayout();
  }

  /** Get the dominant measurement for the aspect ratio. */
  public int getDominantMeasurement() {
    return dominantMeasurement;
  }

  /**
   * Set the dominant measurement for the aspect ratio.
   *
   * @see #MEASUREMENT_WIDTH
   * @see #MEASUREMENT_HEIGHT
   */
  public void setDominantMeasurement(int dominantMeasurement) {
    if (dominantMeasurement != MEASUREMENT_HEIGHT && dominantMeasurement != MEASUREMENT_WIDTH) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid measurement type.");
    }
    this.dominantMeasurement = dominantMeasurement;
    requestLayout();
  }
}
```

Note: One simbol `*` is changed to `/` (read the comments in source)
And this in your `/values/attrs.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="AspectRatioImageView">
        <attr name="aspectRatio" format="float" />
        <attr name="aspectRatioEnabled" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="dominantMeasurement">
            <enum name="width" value="0" />
            <enum name="height" value="1" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then you can use this way in your layout (aspectRatio = width/height):

```
<com.yourpackage.ui.classes.AspectRatioImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:aspectRatio="1.78"
        app:aspectRatioEnabled="true"
        app:dominantMeasurement="width" />
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/2856179)

Comment: Thank you very much, nice example for future custom views